# Showing RSS feed via fetch_feed. How to show the site title of the feed?

Tags: rss, title, feed

Question is simple. Can i get the title and main url of the site from where the posts are loading? Actually i want to linked to the main site.

The url can be found by wordpress function esc_url(); function but what about site title?

The page is here:

http://citystir.com/author/designdons/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$feed = fetch_feed($feedurl);
$channel = $feed->channel;
$blog_title = $channel["title"];
```

Note - I haven't tested this, am relying on my (faulty) memory.

Comment: Actually i am mixing RSS feeds from couple of sites. So, the site title's are needed in the item lavel. I get the site url via `$item->get_base();` Is there any way to find out the title in the simplepie item? I have `print_r` the simple pie item object. I have seen the site title there but don't know how to get it :(

Comment: If the site title is there why can't you get it? add the print_r output to your question

Comment: Sorry, i don't have too much experience with php objects. Here is the print_r http://pastebin.com/1C1RAawV look for the text "Lakeview". Did not paste full output.. its too large.. Thanks!

Comment: Start checking in line 71 you will see the title in line 87 you will see the site url.. Thanks!

Comment: anything? :(

Answer (score 0):

I opted for a more simplistic way.

```
  <?php $title = $item->get_base();

    if($title == "http://mywebsite.com/"){
        $t = "My Website";
    }

        if ($title == "http://mysecondwebsite.com/"){
        $t = 'My Second Website';
    }
    ?>

        //echo results
        <span><?php echo $t; ?></span>
```

I had tried get_channel_tags and get_feed_tags which always returned NULL

Comment: Site url is arbitrary..